# @angular : how to build a directive to add an attribute based on selected route?

Tags: angular, attributes, router, angular-directive

The following code is working fine (the attribute **data-toggle-state**) is correctly set to *active* and *inactive*.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/home']" [attr.data-toggle-state]="router.isActive('/home', true) ? 'active' : 'inactive'">Home</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/admin']" [attr.data-toggle-state]="router.isActive('/admin', true) ? 'active' : 'inactive'">Home</a>
```

However, I want to create a new directive which has the same functionality.

My typescript directive code looks like:

```js
Directive({
  selector: '[xDataToggleState]'
})
export class ToggleStateDirective {

    @Input('xDataToggleState')
    public route: string;

    constructor(private router: Router, private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute, private el: ElementRef, private render: Renderer) {
      this.toggle(this.route);
    }

    private toggle(route: string) {
      if (this.route) {
          this.render.setElementAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'data-toggle-state', this.router.isActive(this.route, false) ? 'active' : 'inactive');
      }
    }
}
```

And the html looks like:

```
<a routerLink]="['/home']" xDataToggleState="/home">Home</a>
```

However, the *this.route* is always undefined? So the directive doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from @yurzui, I was able to get this working. However I used **ngDoCheck()**.

See working code from the directive below:

```typescript
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer, HostListener, OnInit, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Directive({
  selector: '[xDataToggleState]'
})
export class ToggleStateDirective implements OnInit, DoCheck {

  @Input('xDataToggleState')
  public route: string;

  constructor(private router: Router, private el: ElementRef, private render: Renderer) {
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  public ngDoCheck(): void {
    this.toggle(this.route);
  }

  private toggle(route: string) {
    console.debug('route=' + this.route);

    if (this.route) {
      console.debug('this.router.isActive(this.route, false)=' + this.router.isActive(this.route, false));
      this.render.setElementAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'data-toggle-state', this.router.isActive(this.route, false) ? 'active' : 'inactive');
    }
  }
}
```

When I click a menu item, all the items are updated as can be seen from the console log when clicking on the **admin** link.

```
route=/home
this.router.isActive(this.route, false)=false

route=/admin
this.router.isActive(this.route, false)=true

route=/data
this.router.isActive(this.route, false)=false
```